# IBinder in Android Subclass

Tags: java, android, interface

I would like to ask how does IBinder support as a base interface for a remotable object. Hence, how is its functionality applicable for a CountDownTimer in the following code?

```
  public class BackgroundProcessingService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     timer = new CountDownTimer(5 *60 * 1000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               //Some code
                //inactivity = true;
                timer.start();
                Log.v("Timer::", "Started");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
               //Logout
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomePageActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //inactivity = false;
                timer.cancel();
                Log.v("Timer::", "Stoped");
            }
         };
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink How does IBinder achieve its functionality with the following codes

Comment: what IBinder? you return null,  not any valid IBinder...

Comment: @pskink what do you mean? I don't really understand

Comment: you have *"IBinder onBind(Intent intent)"* and you return null from this method,  so what IBinder are you talking about? it's not any valid IBinder,  it's **null**

Comment: hence, does that mean that the activity inside IBinder will not return any result?hence, it would be advisable to remove return null?

Comment: activity inside IBinder? what are you taking about? what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink okay, I have got some general idea after researching, but please correct me if I were to be wrong. The following code is to bind the CountDownTimer function to the backgroundprocessing service, hence, if the following IBinder is to return null, does that mean  that I wouldn't allow the CountDownTimer to be bounded?

Comment: i think you should first read this:  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html